# data-icon in jquery mobile does not show up in ruby on rails 2.3.4

Tags: jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using jquery-mobile for 1 of my applications in Rails 2.3.4.

The following code
    li data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right"><%= link_to "Post", [my parameters] %>

does not show the data icon, "plus". I am wondering why.

Any ideas please.

Comment: Are you using data-role="listview"? Add the class of ui-li-icon

Comment: Yes, I am using data-role="listview". I dont get what you mean by adding the class of ul-li-icon. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Question: Are you trying to change the 'standard' arrow icon on the right?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change the standard icon that shows up on the right end of every <li> item.

Answer (score 0):

The original question is a little unclear to me, but from the comments, it looks like you're trying to find out how to change the icon in listview from the standard arrow.

To do this, add a data-split-icon property to the ul tag - setting it to one of the icon names from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

For example:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="star"> 
   <li><h3><a>list item 1</a></h3><a>link title</a></li> 
   <li><h3><a>list item 2</a></h3><a>link title</a></li>
   <li><h3><a>list item 3</a></h3><a>link title</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of the standard arrow icon, that gives you a list with pretty stars.

Hope that helps

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I will try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself - it is due to the fact that Rails uses a 1.4 version of jQuery by default - you need to be using jQuery 1.5

If you want to get started quickly then use the jQuery CDN hosted files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js">
```